# Window 10 send multicast with "a socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network" error

Tags: java, windows, multicast

I have a testing program sending multicast in loopback interface in Windows 10, but return "a socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network" error.

After some study, I found that I need to start another program as multicast receiver first, before starting the sender program to solve it.

Anyone knows why? or any other way to solve this issue in Windows 10? thanks

Comment: Multicast groups have to be 'created'.  If there's no group known to the relevant router, it presumably (I have not bothered to read the RFC) treats it like an unreachable network.    But why is this an issue that needs "solving"?  If you don't care that no-one's listening to what you send, ignore the errors.